# Will Flyway Enterprise Edition allow SqlServer 2012 data base migration Automate process

Tags: flyway

I am using Sql Server 2012 where Flyway Community Edition is not accepting and throwing error. Enterprise edition is supported but not Community Edition.

Will Database migration work in Enterprise edition for SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about you read the product advertising for Flyway? It should name the supported databases.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 is only supported in Flyway Enterprise edition. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver.

Note that DB support is guaranteed in Enterprise edition for 10 years after the general availability release. So Flyway may drop support for [SQL Server 2012](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2012/04/02/sql-server-2012-released.aspx) in Enterprise edition in or after 2022. See https://flywaydb.org/download/faq#how-long-are-database-releases-supported-in-each-edition-of-flyway